# Set (copy) Lookup field based on another column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i thought this would be easy, a simple sharepoint workflow to copy contents of one field into a lookup field  (as you can do when you manually copy/paste from quick edit screen)

I have two lists, one with machine inventory and the other a document library containing service records.. i want to be able to link them using lookup field link.

any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps:

- open the library (where you want to have the lookup column)/
- on Ribbon select '`create column`'--> give column name: Vendor Site number (based on your needs)
- Description:
- Require this column contains information: Yes - if it is a mandatory field.
- Enforce unique values: No.
- Get Information from: (select your list name), then select column from where you need to get the data.
- on Relationship: you can select "`Restrict delete`" (so that original field on the list cannot be deleted without deleting this)

Comment: thank you for your response, but i already have the lookup field column added, i just need to be able to have a workflow copy it from "vendor site number" to "unit".   I can get it to work by copying the Vendor site to another column, just not the lookup column

Comment: You mean vendor site list is a parent list and list contain "Unit" is list containing lookup of Parent list. On which list you are running WF ?  Can you come up with more descriptive scenario.

Comment: In my scenario, i have to create a new item in list B (with few column from ListA) as soon as a new item was created in ListA. ListB was having a lookup column for ListA. I have used CreateItem action of WF2010.  I copied succesfully

Comment: after you create the lookup column on the list/library, change view to Datasheet mode and copy the data from the field on Original list/library and paste it to the Destination list/library.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this.. but the strange thing is, it will copy / paste (from datasheet view), but not using a workflow..

so for me i have Unit number already in List B, then when i create a new Item in List A, and i want to 'link' it to the unit number in List B, i want to have a workflow do that... so i want to copy the content of the Vendor site number (List A) to the Unit number (List B)

Comment: you may need to create an event receiver (code) to do that using ItemAdded() functionality for a new item entry to have lookup column data. workflow may not support this scenario.